# AVAudioPlayer not found in iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I need to add AVAudioPlayer Framework in project but don't find it.Is it deprecated in iOS 6?
If yes then what i m supposed to use to play audio file mp3. Will mediaplayer framework will work to play audiofile mp3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> AVAudioPlayer Framework

No-no. AVAudioPlayer is a *class,* not a framework. If you're intending to use this class, you have to link to the AVFoundation *framework* - in case you're using Xcode, you can add this framework on the "build phases" tab in the "link with libraries" section.

Comment: added avfoundation framework to my app and in properties added @property (nonatomic, retain)avaudioplayer *audioplayer; but message says unknown type name avaudioplayer

Comment: @user1452248 Do you have `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` at the top of your header file?

Comment: How can i forget to add that. Thanks. Some times you miss to figure little mistake. Appreciate your help so much.